# Required ErrorMessage conteúdo dinâmico

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Utilizando Asp.Net MVC 5 preciso criar uma mensagem de requerido com o seguinte formato:

> "Campo de preenchimento obrigatório! [Razão Social]"

Normalmente faria assim:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo de preenchimento obrigatório! [Razão Social]")]
[Display(Name = "Razão Social")]
[StringLength(60)]
public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
```

Gostaria de usar no ErrorMessag do Required o Name que esta no Display. Assim ao alterar este valor o nome será alterado automaticamente na mensagem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma opção seria criar uma classe estática e colocar os diferentes tipos de mensagens lá:

```
public static class ValidationMessage
{
    public const string Required = "Campo de preenchimento obrigatório! [{0}]";
    public const string StringLength = "O campo {0} deve conter entre {2} e {1} caracteres.";            
}
```

E na sua classe:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessage.Required)]
[StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessage.StringLength)]
[Display(Name = "Razão Social")]
public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
```